# How to create an if else statement to delete item from angular

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, express

I am trying to delete an item if the item's quantity is 0 but if the item's quantity is not = 0 can't delete it and send back to the front end an error message

Here is my components.ts:

```
  productID: string;
  productData: any;
  error = "";

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.getOneProduct();
  }

  getOneProduct() {
    let observable = this.httpService.oneProduct(this.productID);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.productData = data;
    });
  }

  onDelete(id) {
    const observable = this.httpService.deleteProduct(id);
    observable.subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.qty < 0) {
        this.error = "Qty need to be 0 to delete item";
        this.router.navigate([`products/${id}`]);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(["products"]);
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
  <div *ngIf="error">
    <p class="text-danger">{{error}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info" *ngFor="let product of productData">
    <h5> Name: {{product.name}}</h5>
    <h5> Qty: {{product.qty}}</h5>
    <h5> Price: ${{product.price}}</h5>

    <button class="btn btn-secondary" [routerLink]="['/products']">Back</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" (click)="onDelete(product._id)">Delete</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: the button delete item! It's worked even item's qty is not at 0

Answer (score 1):

In your `onDelete` method, change this :

`if (data.qty < 0) {...}`

which mean that you want to delete everything that is over 0, by:

`if (data.qty === 0) {...}`

Also inverse your condition. if qty === 0 then you delete, else you throw the error.

Also, you should check for the product quantity before to do any http call. With the id you can easily do it, it will avoid useless api calls.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`if (data.qty > 0){. //Show error..}
else{..delete..}`